# SSO vs TLS/SSL in Azure app service context

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice

I have couple of questions.

What is the difference between SSO and TSL/SSL?

If an web app is deployed in Azure app service, from where can I find the SSO related certificates installed? And, how to check the SSO certificates names?

I can see only the TSL/SSL from Azure portal. But no clue on SSO part?

Comment: sso (single sign on) and tls (transport layer security) are two really different things. could you explain a little more on your use case so we can understand the confusion please ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got you. You are with me. My application is using SSO ( looks like old, as per SSO team) and I have to update new SSO certificates for the application( developed in .Net core) . SSO team going to update the certificates from their side and asking me to update the same from application side, so that everything will work smoothly. However, the confusion is, where can I update this SSO certificates? In Azure I can only see the TLS/SSL. Am I missing something in Azure portal? Or, this SSO is nothing to do with Azure? And I have to look at somewhere else?

Comment: I think, I got the SSO certificates located in code folder.Is there any way to deploy single file? instead of publishing whole application from Visual Studio Studio?